# page shows before functions on 'pagebeforeshow' is completed in jquery mobile with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

When I move from **page A** to **page B**,
I made page B prepare some UI's (pre-filling texts, pre-selecting some options, etc) on 'pagebeforeshow':

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pageB', function(){
    prepare_some_UIs();
});
```

But sometimes, page B shows up before finishing up 'pagebeforeshow' tasks.
and sometimes, after completing 'pagebeforeshow' tasks making some UIs not ready.

How can I ensure that all 'pagebeforeshow' tasks are fully completed before page B shows up? (except making 'pagebeforeshow' events lighter)

Comment: do you have any async task in `prepare_some_UIs();`? in that case, show the jQuery Mobile loader until tasks are finished

Comment: do u mean async $.ajax task? no..

Comment: but i have some local sql tasks

Comment: If those tasks are async (do they work with callbacks?) then you have to rethink the workflow

Comment: hm i guess i should think about this more.. thanks!